# Solved - How to validate multiple :unique email fields in Laravel 10 Livewire v3?

Tags: laravel, validation, dynamic, unique, laravel-livewire

Edit: I just found the answer, i need it to specify the real table column and ignore the given id

```
unique:company_emails,email
```

im trying to get this working.
First thing, i don't know why but livewire doesn't get my email dynamic fields when they are empty, so can't validate empty emails, i tried just using livewire to create the dynamic fields but didnt work, js the same. I did something to patch that for the moment.

Leaving that aside, my main issue now is that i can't validate multiples emails with the method unique:, even if i set the $rules like

```
          'email' => ['required' ,'array'],
            'email.*' => 'required|unique:company_emails',
```

formatted email array:

```
array:3 [▼ // app\Livewire\CreateCompaniesLw.php:67
  0 => null
  1 => "jorge@email.com"
  2 => null
]
```

$rules output:

```
array:10 [▼ // app\Livewire\CreateCompaniesLw.php:70
  "rut" => array:4 [▶]
  "name" => "required|string"
  "phone" => "required"
  "regions_id" => "required|integer"
  "provinces_id" => "required|integer"
  "communes_id" => "required|integer"
  "address" => "required"
  "email.0" => "required|email|unique:company_emails"
  "email.1" => "required|email|unique:company_emails"
  "email.2" => "required|email|unique:company_emails"
]
```

code:

```
use Actions;
    public $rut, $name, $phone, $regions_id, $provinces_id, $communes_id, $address;
    public $email = [];
    public $fields = [];
    public $email_qty;

    #[On('input-delete')]
    public function rmInputData($i)
    {
        $this->reset($i);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $rules = [
            'rut' => ['required', 'min:3', 'unique:companies', new RutValidator],
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'regions_id' => 'required|integer',
            'provinces_id' => 'required|integer',
            'communes_id' => 'required|integer',
            'address' => 'required',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => "El campo razón social requerido",
            'phone.required' => 'El campo teléfono es requerido',
            'regions_id.required' => 'El campo region es requerido',
            'provinces_id.required' => 'El campo provincia es requerido',
            'communes_id.required' => 'El campo comuna es requerido',
            'address.required' => 'El campo dirección es requerido',
        ];

        $this->rut = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($this->rut, 0, -1)) . '-' . substr($this->rut, -1);

        if ($this->email_qty === null) :
            $this->email_qty = 1;
        endif;

        $this->fields = new SplFixedArray($this->email_qty);
        $email_label_number = 1;
        foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
            $this->email[$key] =   (array_key_exists($key, $this->email) ? $this->email[$key] : null);
            $rules['email.' . $key] = ['required', 'email', 'unique:company_emails'];
            $messages['email.' . $key . '.required'] = 'El campo email ' . $email_label_number . ' es requerido';
            $messages['email.' . $key . '.email'] = 'El formato del campo email ' . $email_label_number . ' no es válido.';
            $email_label_number++;
        }
        $this->fields = null;

        $data = $this->validate($rules, $messages);

        DB::beginTransaction();
```

This is the error i get and i understand the reason behind it, but i thought that laravel will be doing something with the ".0"

SQL Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email.0' in 'where clause' 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `company_emails`
where
  `email`.`0` = juanito@correo.cl
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english.
Btw, i just started programming with laravel/livewire so i don't know many things, i did read the validation array from the docs of laravel but didnt work for me.

Comment: How do you validate if email has a valid format? or a password have a uppercase, lowercase and number?